# Why does conda install non-compatible jupyterlab dependency (prometheus_client) in my environment?

Tags: conda, python-3.7, jupyter-lab

I am running conda via a standard miniconda3 installation on Ubuntu 20.04. I need a Python 3.7 environment and have the following simplified conda environment file (`test_env.yaml`):

```yaml
name: test-env
channels:
    - conda-forge
    - nodefaults
dependencies:
    - python=3.7
    - ipykernel
    - jupyterlab
```

After creating the environment using `conda env create -f test_env.yaml` and activating it, I try to import `jupyterlab` in a Python session but get an import error:

```bash
(test-env) [~]$ python
Python 3.7.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 26 2021, 06:08:21) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jupyterlab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/olamarre/miniconda3/envs/test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .handlers.announcements import (  # noqa
  File "/home/olamarre/miniconda3/envs/test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/handlers/announcements.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.base.handlers import APIHandler
  File "/home/olamarre/miniconda3/envs/test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 18, in <module>
    import prometheus_client
  File "/home/olamarre/miniconda3/envs/test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prometheus_client/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import (
  File "/home/olamarre/miniconda3/envs/test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prometheus_client/metrics.py", line 5, in <module>
    from typing import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/home/olamarre/miniconda3/envs/test-env/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
>>>
```

One of the jupyterlab dependencies, `prometheus_client`, tries to make an import that only works in Python 3.8 and above, not Python 3.7. That `prometheus_client` package version (0.18) is thus incompatible with my environment. If I explicitly tell conda to install an earlier version of the same package (by adding `prometheus_client=0.17` to the dependencies in the environment file), the problem is fixed.

My question is: **Could this be an issue with the conda configuration of the dependency tree of `jupyterlab`? (and if so, how can I flag this issue to get it fixed?) Or could this be an issue on my end? (and if so, how should I debug it?)**

What makes me suspiscious is that I recently created a separate Python 3.11 environment that also installed `jupyterlab` (same way, but with `python=3.11` in the conda environment file), so I am wondering if the cached `prometheus_client` package for that environment is being reused for the Python 3.7 environment.

Answer (score 1):

Potential answer to my own question - I just noticed in the [prometheus conda package files](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/prometheus_client/files) that the upgrade to 0.18 was made a few days ago, and the requirements only impose a python >= 3.6. I suspect this might be the issue, will follow up with the developers (opened a [github issue](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/issues/977)).

[image]

Comment: Yes, Conda Forge is pretty lax about imposing constraints on its recipes. Since 3.7 is EOL, no one is actively testing backward compatibility with it on new packages. If you really have to use such an old version of Python then you should consider imposing upper bounds on packages so you only get versions contemporary to when 3.7 was still used. But I also would agree that conda-build/grayskull should probably start imposing `python >=3.8` on its newer `noarch` recipes.

Comment: Yeah, eventually I will need to upgrade my codebase. But since the codebase on github correctly requires python >=3.8 for that package version, I think they should still reflect that requirement in conda as well.